# Is there an implementation of higher kinded types in typed lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, abstract-data-types, prolog

I can see that we can do [higher kinded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) `( * -> *) -> *` in [Scala](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/09/scala-types-of-a-higher-kind/) and [Haskell](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html) and other languages. I'm looking for a simpler vanilla implementation of just the basic static type checking system - perhaps in [Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10340710/15441) or [MiniKanren](https://github.com/namin/minikanren-confo).

My question is: **Is there an implementation of higher kinded types in typed lambda calculus?**

Comment: This is pretty ambiguous. Is Lambda Calculus the language of implementation, or the base language that you've added a higher-kinded type system to?

Comment: I took Lambda Calculus to be the 'theoretical language' that was then implemented by an 'actual' language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you find mainstream languages with HKTs simpler than Scala and
Haskell. And even those don't implement HKTs fully.
Tim Sheard's [Ωmega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9mega)   and
some interactive proof assistants have HKTs too.

Chapters 29 and 30 of   [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) 
show exactly how HKTs are added to a typing-system and how to do type-checking with HKTs. Why not do it yourself, it's instructive!

Comment: Yeah - its looking like TAPL or Practical Foundations of Programming Languages - thanks.

Comment: Could you expand on why Scala and Haskell don't support HKTs fully? A link perhaps?

Comment: @hawkeye It depends on what you mean by HKTs. For me $\lambda\omega$ (from Barendregt's $\lambda$-cube)  is
the prototypical type-theory with full HKTs. However, type-inference
for $\lambda\omega$ (not to mention $F_{\omega}$) doesn't appear to be
decidable, because it's probably equivalent to higher-order
unification (which is known to be undecidable).  For example, say you
want to unify $f\ x = List\ a$ where $f$ has kind $* \rightarrow *$, then you loose the principal-kind property.  (Continued below.)

Comment: If you
restrict which kind-functions are allowed as inhabitants  of $* \rightarrow *$, in particular  forbid
$\lambda k^{*}. k$,  you can get away with first-order
unification. That's what Haskell does.  Not many accessible papers
around on HKTs, maybe M. P. Jones, "A system of constructor classes:
overloading and implicit higher-order polymorphism", which describes
Haskell's approach.

Comment: Scala's typing system is in flux. Have a look at the latest DOT paper [The Essence of Dependent Object Types](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/02/03/essence-of-scala.html) to see where the journey is probably going.